# Guardar en una cookie un valor de un enlace en Angular 5

Tags: cookies, angular5, angular

Estoy intentando coger un valor de un `<a>` en `angular 5` y pasarlo a el `ts` del componente para guardarlo en una `cookie`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="pulsar()" [routerLink]="['/rutas']" 
ng-value="Madrid" id="name" >
```

Y en el `ts`

```
pulsar(){
var name='name';
this.cookieService.set('Rutas', 'name' );
console.log(name);
}
```

En fin, estoy intentado que al pulsar en ese botón se añada a una cookie el valor `Madrid`.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con localStorage.

```html
pulsar(){
var name='name';
localStorage.setItem("rutas", name);
console.log(localStorage.rutas);
}
```

Comment: nada, sigue sin funcionar... Gracias

Answer (score 0):

para obtener el valor del `localstorage` se utiliza:

```
name = localstorage.getItem('name');
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/322266)